# Searching for Points close to a Vector in 3D space

Tags: c++, algorithm, math, 3d

I'm terrible with math, but I have a situation where I need to find all points in a 3D space that are arbitrarily close to a vector being projected through that same space.  The points can be stored in any fashion the algorithm calls for, not that I can think of any particularly beneficial ordering for them.

Are there any existing C++ algorithms for this feat?   And if so (or not), what kind of mathematical concept does or would it entail, since I'd love to attempt to understand it and tie my brain into a pretzel.

( This algorithm would be operating on a space with perhaps 100,000 points in it, it would need to test around 1,000,000 vectors, and need to complete those vectors within 1/30th of a second.  I of course doubt if any algorithm can perform this feat at all, but it'll be fun to see if that's true or not. )

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what exactly are you doing?

Comment: @clairvoire - sorry, I didn't mean to frighten you away in the comments of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7136024/legality-of-emulating-a-technique-seen-in-a-tech-demo and definitely not cause you to delete it. I ought have been more tactful. (And it is deleted so I have to comment here as I cannot there).

Comment: @msw - Nyah, that question was outside of SO's scope, reading into the related questions that dealt with more or less the same thing show me that.  You had more than enough tact, don't worry about that!

Comment: @Mike - I want to try my hand at writing a renderer that works with floating points in a space, similar to a voxel renderer but the position of the points not being aligned to a 3D grid.  The vectors being tested correspond to the pixels on the screen (hence the estimate of 1 million).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would probably want to store your points in some spatial data structure. The ones that come to mind are:

1. [oct-trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octree)
2. [BSP trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_space_partitioning)
3. [kd-trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree)

They have slightly different properties. An oct-tree divides the entire world up into 8 equally sized cubes, organized to themselves form a larger cube. Each of these cubes are then in turn split into 8, evenly sized, cubes. You keep splitting the cubes until you have less than some number of points in a cube. With this tree structure, you can quite easily traverse the tree, extracting all points that *may* intersect a given cube. Once you have that list of points, you can test them one at a time. Since your test geometry is a sphere (distance from a point) you would circumscribe a cube around the sphere and get the points that may intersect it. As an optimization, you may also *inscribe* a cube in your circle, and anything that for sure intersects that, you can simply include in your hit-set right away.

The BSP tree is a *Binary space partitioning* tree. It's a tree of planes in 3-space, forming a binary tree. The main problem of using this for your problem is that you might have to do a lot of square roots while traversing it, to find the distance to the planes. The principle is the same though, once you have fewer than some number of points you form a leaf with those points in it. All leaves in a BSP tree are convex polygons (except for the leaves that are along the perimeter, which will be infinitely large polygons). When building the BSP, you want to split the points in half for each step, to truly get O(log n) searches.

The kd-tree is a special case of BSP, where all planes are axis aligned. This typically speeds up tests against them quite significantly, but doesn't allow you to optimize the planes based on your set of points quite as well.

I don't know of any c++ libraries that implement these, but I'm sure there are plenty of them. These are fairly common techniques used in video games, so you might want to look at game engines.

Comment: Thank you!  I'll give these 3 a look over, but I have to say I'm pretty smitten by the oct-tree so far.  For optimization's sake, I could also just check to see if points are within the bounds of an axis aligned square instead of a circle, when checking for proximity.  Ironically, this would actually yield more accurate results for what I'm after.

Answer (score 1):

It might help your understanding of octrees when you can think of it as a curve that fills the space traversing every coordinate only once and w/o crossing itself. The curve maps the 3d complexity to a 1d complexity. There are some of this monster curve, like the z curve, the hilbert curve, and the moore curve. The latter is a copy of 4 hilbert curves and has very good space fills quality. But isn't a search for the closest points not solved with dijkstra algorithm?

Comment: Looking up that particular algorithm,I don't think it would be.  The act of finding points close to a vector is needed only to effectively give the vector a width, since a widthless vector would otherwise never intersect a perfectly tiny point.  I think the octree though would be very useful as a broadphase, when testing for which points to specifically test